# react-native-firebase-messaging mocking with jest

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

I am trying to mock Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), from `@react-native-firebase/messaging`.So far here is my mock:

```js
jest.mock('@react-native-firebase/messaging', () => ({
  hasPermission: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
  subscribeToTopic: jest.fn(),
  deleteToken: jest.fn(),
  unsubscribeFromTopic: jest.fn(),
  registerForRemoteNotifications: jest.fn(),
  requestPermission: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
  getToken: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('myMockToken')),
  getAPNSToken: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('myMockToken')),
  onTokenRefresh: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('myMockToken')),
  onMessage: jest.fn(),
  isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications: jest.mock(false),
  isAutoInitEnabled: jest.mock(false),
}));
```

But when I run my test I get:

```
   Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.

      at invariant (packages/mobile/node_modules/invariant/invariant.js:40:15)
      at RNFBNativeEventEmitter.invariant (packages/mobile/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/EventEmitter/NativeEventEmitter.js:36:7)
      at new RNFBNativeEventEmitter (node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/lib/internal/RNFBNativeEventEmitter.js:24:5)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/lib/internal/RNFBNativeEventEmitter.js:48:16)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/lib/internal/registry/nativeModule.js:21:1)
```

Which tells me that I still have to mock some other functions. What am I missing in here?

Comment: Provide the code you want to test

Answer (score 3):

I turn out that I was not mocking properly. I created a

```
__mocks__/@react-native-firebase/messaging.js.
```

In that file I write:

```
module.exports = {
  hasPermission: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
  subscribeToTopic: jest.fn(),
  unsubscribeFromTopic: jest.fn(),
  requestPermission: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
  getToken: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('myMockToken')),
};
```

Also In my setup jest I have:

```
reactNative.NativeModules.RNCNetInfo = {
  getCurrentState: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
  addListener: jest.fn(),
  removeListeners: jest.fn(),
};
```

Comment: Can you please add whole code to test @react-native-firbase/app